# How to Bind Data to Dynamically Created Form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to build a form which starts with a drop-down and depending upon the option selected creates a second drop down.  I can create the second drop down using FormEvents just fine, but what I can't do is pre-select an option in that second drop-down once it is created.  Does anyone know how to bind data to a form element created via FormEvents?

Comment: which event are you using?

Comment: Both PRE_BIND and PRE_SET_DATA